# Django best practice on relative path from an AJAX request

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am currently failing at trying to read a CSV file stored in my django static repository from an AJAX request.

```
Failed to load resource: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/users/feedbacks/data.csv
the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there a best practice for this to work properly as well in production?

here is the **js**:

```
if (replayCSV){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/static/users/feedbacks/data.csv",
            dataType: "csv",
            success: function(data) {readData(data);}
         });
        console.log(dataToRead);
    });
}
```

And my **django project structure** looks like:

```
main_repository
-...
-project_folder
--app_folder
---static
----js
-----therequest.js
static_repository
-static
--users
---feedbacks
----data.csv
```

Comment: What does it mean *main_repository* and *static_repository*? Where is `manage.py`? It's obviously it can't find the file, because it is in a directory *static_repository*, which is not included in the path. But that alone won't solve the problem. The location of the *js* file isn't important. It's important where the *js* file is called.

Comment: What is responsible for serving content from `static_repository`? How is it configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**
I am leaving the question as is and the solution below if someone run into similar problem. Simply enough, the dataType was wrong.

change `dataType: "csv"` with `dataType: "text"`

This will allow to get the csv file properly according to the given path